# how to save the displaying map and plotted data in rviz on an image file

Tags: ros, data, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey All,

I use rviz for visualization of path planning. How do I save the displaying map and plotted paths traversed by the robot on an image file like png or jpeg? I need to import the plotted data on the map from rviz to my paper as an image.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252121/how-to-save-the-displaying-map-and-plotted-data-in-rviz-on-an-image-file/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/indigo/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Azhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27936/azhar/) with karma: 100 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0